# Can a Demon Weapon also be a Weapon Meister?

Tags: soul-eater

So I just started watching Soul Eater and have the basics pretty much and u was wandering. Could a Demon Weapon also be a weapon meister? This got me thinking when watching the Thompson Sisters defend themselves against an army of mummies can someone shed some light on this? I know the sisters are just weapons belonging to Death the Kid.

Answer (score 5):

The *Weapon* ability in Soul Eater is basically determined at birth. You either can transform into a weapon or you can't. There's no confusion about that. But the *Meisters* are a bit different.

To be a *Meister* basically means to be able to perform well in pair with a *Weapon*. Not everybody can do that, but even among the *Meisters*, not all of them can perform well enough to be considered a serious threat or a great combo. You could say that a successful combo can do the Soul Resonance thing and unleash their full battle potential. And it doesn't really matter if there's more than one *Weapon* in a combo or no *Meisters* (non-*Weapon*) at all. Thompson sisters show that they can do just fine both in the role of a *Meister* and a *Weapon*.

So all members of a combo can be *Weapons*, but the Soul Resonance best occurs when there is a specialist non-*Weapon* *Meister* in it. At least that's what can be concluded from the series.